# postgreSQL : JOIN and GROUP BY to get the right query result

Tags: arrays, postgresql, join, group-by

I am a postgreSQL newbie and I am stuck on the following queries.

The desirable output would be

```
id |   name      | address | description | employees
1  |  'company1' | 'asdf'  |  'asdf'     | [{id: 1, name: 'Mark'}, {id: 2, name: 'Mark'}, {id: 3, name: 'Steve'}, {id: 4, name: 'Mark'}]
2 ...
3 ...
5  |  'company5' | 'asdf   | 'adsf'      | []
```

My current query(which not working is)

```
SELECT companies.* ,employees.*,json_agg(companies_employees.*) as "item"
FROM
  companies_employees
  JOIN companies ON companies_employees.COMPANY_id = companies.ID 
  JOIN employees ON companies_employees.EMPLOYEE_id = employees.ID
GROUP BY companies.ID, companies.NAME, companies.ADDRESS,companies.DESCRIPTION,employees.ID, employees.NAME
```

There are 3 tables:

```
companies : ID, NAME, ADDRESS, DESCRIPTION
employees : ID, NAME, SALARY, ROLE
companies_employees : EMPLOYEE_ID, COMPANY_ID 
(CONSTRAINT companies_employees_employee_fkey FOREIGN KEY(employee_id) REFERENCES employees(id),
CONSTRAINT companies_employees_company_fkey FOREIGN KEY(company_id) REFERENCES companies(id) )
```

The sample table is [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/27982/29][here]

Maybe "GROUP BY" is not a right one to use.

Would you please guide me to the right direction?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8849a/1

Your issue is that you are displaying employee data and using that in your group by condition.  Those fields have unique values.  You want to group only on the company information:

```
SELECT
  companies.*,json_agg(employees.*) as "employees"
FROM
  companies_employees
  JOIN companies ON companies_employees.COMPANY_id = companies.ID
  JOIN employees ON companies_employees.EMPLOYEE_id = employees.ID
GROUP BY 
  companies.ID, 
  companies.NAME, 
  companies.ADDRESS,
  companies.DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: Awesome.. This is what I was looking for.  You saved my day.  Thank you!